# Question about aggregate function

Tags: r, spss, aggregation

I'm an R user and I'm trying to rewrite some second hand SPSS code in R. Could someone give me a basic idea of what this code is achieving?:

```
AGGREG OUTFILE=*
/BREAK = subj task cond
/lat wind inwind primehit primefa =
mean(lat wind inwind primehit primefa)
/Ntrials = n.
```

Some background info is that `subj`, `task`, `cond`, `lat`, `wind`, `inwind`, `primhit`, and `primefa` are all variables in a dataset I'm using.

Comment: For and outstanding tutorial on this, see [SPSS AGGREGATE Command](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-aggregate-command/).

Answer (score 2):

Here's what it would look like in R:

```
#subj, task, cond, lat, wind, inwind, primhit, primefa
#Creating some fake data for you to aggregate by
df<-data.frame(subj=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(3,10)),
           task=rep(c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5)),3),
           cond=rep(rep(c(rep(T,3),rep(F,2)),2),3),
           lat=rnorm(30,100,20),wind=rnorm(30,10,10),inwind=rnorm(30,5,1),
           primhit=rnorm(30,5000,75),primefa=rnorm(30,200,30))
aggregate(df[,-c(1:3)],by=list(df$subj,df$task,df$cond),FUN="mean")
```

The (truncated) output should be similar to this (will vary due to rnorm):

```
   Group.1 Group.2 Group.3       lat      wind   inwind  primhit  primefa
1        1       A   FALSE 102.96070  5.637264 5.213994 5043.498 213.3119
2        2       A   FALSE 114.91123 11.161194 5.004008 5055.676 221.1172
....
11       2       B    TRUE  97.04035  6.450370 4.755714 5113.725 196.4184
12       3       B    TRUE 114.92453 12.888350 4.667839 5022.614 199.3125
```

Essentially, the SPSS code is doing the same thing where the /BREAK is the BY list and your third line is redefining the variables to take on the mean for the given subject, task, and condition.  The /Ntrials is giving the number of cases for the given group by.  You could do something like `aggregate(df[,1)],by=list(df$subj,df$task,df$cond),FUN="length")`.

If you ever need to look something up for SPSS, I'd recommend ats.ucla.edu (http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/seminars/spss_syntax08/default08_part2.htm).  They have some of the most comprehensive tutorials out there.